# Bash: How to run a script in background with "&" and use "||" to run something else on failures?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I'm trying to let a command run in the background, but also use the "||" syntax to execute a different command if the first one failed. Example:

```
$( <run-this-in-background> & || <run-this-if-failed>)
```

However **I'm getting a syntax error**:

```
command substitution: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `||'
```

**This is the exact line:**

```
$(./temptwo.sh & || rc=$?)
```

My full code is as follows...
I know it seems a bit weird to do `rc=$?` when I could just do that in the following line, however we are using a logger that will exit your program if any line exits with $? != 0, so the way we get around it is by using "./someCommand || rc=$?" which will exit with "0", but also give us the return code.

```
#default success code: 
rc=0 
#run temptwo.sh in the background. If it fails, set rc=$?
$(./temptwo.sh & || rc=$? )
#Trying to get the process id of "temptwo.sh" below (not sure if works)
pid=$! 
#Wait until the process finishes
wait $pid
```

Comment: Unless you wait until it has finished, how will you know that it has failed?

Comment: When I do "$?" after the "wait" command, it gets the exit code. The "rc" never has the right exit code though, so I just throw that one away lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/temptwo.sh & pid=$! ; wait $pid || rc=$?
```

Doesn't make much sense IMHO, though.

```
/temptwo.sh & pid=$! ; wait $pid ; rc=$?
if [ "$rc" -gt 0 ]; then
...
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Yeah it definitely feels odd.. thank you for answering my question even though the idea is weird ^-^