# why does using &(bg) before &&(and) gives me error in bash script

Tags: linux, shell

`[[ -n $program ]] && echo "$program" && setsid $program "$arg" & && exit 0` 
gives me "syntax error near unexpected token `&&'"

`[[ -n $program ]] && echo "$program" && { setsid $program "$arg" & } && exit 0` 
works fine

can someone help me understand this is there any difference in using brackts there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I test if a background job failed before it exits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454337/how-can-i-test-if-a-background-job-failed-before-it-exits) or [Bash: How to run a script in background with "&" and use "||" to run something else on failures?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432434/70524)

Comment: You can't get the exit status of a backgrounded program until it exits, so what's the `&&` supposed to be doing there? And the exit status of `setsid $program "$arg" &` is always going to be true, so what is the `exit 0` supposed to be conditional on?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the Bash manpage:

> A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by **one** of the
> operators `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `||`, and optionally terminated by one of
> `;`, `&`, or `<newline>`.

Therefore I assume that its parser will see `& &&` as a syntax error.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the "_why?_" of the question

Comment: "why does using & before && gives me an error in bash script?" : because you can't separate a list with more than one control operator. It's an error on the syntactical level. I don't see how this does'nt answer the "why" of the question.

Comment: Yes - `& &&` is inconsistent with the grammar that Bash accepts.  Hence it's a syntax error.  Perfectly clear.